# How to calculate the summation of a function over some values, in MAT LAB?

Tags: matlab

What MATLAB command should be used to evaluate the sum of `f(i)`s, where, for example, `i=1..15`? I see `numeric::sum(f(i), i=a..b)` in the help, but I get the error:

> Error: Unexpected MAT LAB operator

by entering the command: `numeric::sum(i,i=1..100)`

Comment: `sum( f(1:15) )` ? In what help did you see the syntax `::` being used? Are you sure it is Matlab ?

Comment: @Hoki the OP probably refers to the MuPAD [`numeric::sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-sum.html) function.

Comment: Matlab R2014 documentation; Symbolic Math Toolbox/ MuPAD/ Calculus/ Series/ Summation -> numeric::sum

Comment: @Shai. Thanks for the explanation. I see the first lines of your link also provide an explanation to the OP's problem : _"**Use only in the MuPAD Notebook Interface.** This functionality does not run in MATLAB."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [symsum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symsum.html) will do it.
For example the commands:

```
syms k
symsum(k^2, 0, 3)
```

compute:

```
(0)^2 + (1)^2 + (2)^2 + (3)^2
```

which equals 14

Answer (score 2):

The command [`numeric::sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-sum.html) is not a Matlab command but rather a [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/mupad.html) command.

In order to sum entries in Matlab you should use [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) function:

```
sum( 1:100 )
```

Evaluates to

```
5050
```

Comment: this function returns the sum of some array elements; But how to evaluate the sum of a series with a given expression which defines the terms of that series? What I'm looking for, is function which accepts as arguments : an expression, a variable which the expression is defined with and a range which the variable changes in

Answer (score 1):

1)define your variable 
ex:

```
var=1:1:1000;
```

or

```
var=35:3:200;
```

etc.

2)convert it to a column vector

```
var=var';
```

3)use these functions: a)sum ,b)arrayfun

```
res=sum(arrayfun(@your_desired_function,var));
```

4)this way you could sum over any arbitrary function which you defined before(even with more than one input argument);

5)another way is to use for loop

```
var=3:5:4500;
s=0;
for i=1:numel(var)
    //do your calculation on v(i) and stor the result in res for example
    res=v(i)^2+3*(v(i))+5;
    s=s+res;
end
```